# Dominance Matrices when teams play twice

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I'm familiar with finding two step dominances when the players involved have only played each other once - you create a matrix of results filled with 1's (for wins) and 0's (for losses/ties), then square it. To find the power of each team you square the matrix then add it to itself.

So, how does the process change when you have teams involved that have played each other more than once and there are 2's introduced into the matrix? I'm working this with Matlab (Octave actually), and when I enter the matrix, which is actually a 31x31 matrix showing the results from the 2001-2002 NFL season, then square it, I get results showing that teams had dominance over themselves - like this:

Original Matrix (abbreviated):

```
   Buf    Ind    Mia     NE   NYJ
```

Buf        0           0            0              0         1

Ind    2            0            0              0         1

Mia   2            2            0              1         0

NE    2            2            1              0         1

NYJ  1            1            2              1          0

Squared Matrix (abbreviated):

```
   Buf    Ind    Mia     NE   NYJ
```

Buf   1            1            2            1            0

Ind   2            1            2            2            2

Mia   8            3            1            1            5

NE   10           4            2            2            4

NYJ   9            8            1            3            3

So how do I address the issue of the results showing a team having dominance over itself and get to my final power numbers like I would in a "played only once" scenario?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've never done anything like this before but, I think it would make sense to separate out different sets of games into different results matrices (one matrix per round robin as it were) and calculate dominance matrix from each separately and then add the two together.  Hopefully this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same problem with soccer games with 2 points for a win, 1 for a draw and 0 for a loss, but I belief that is is possible to have a team with dominance over itself because they have beaten the team that beat them (or for soccer the draw). Therefore, I would say that you can just continue on as is. (p.s. I am a Year 11 Maths C student, so there may be other explainations for this)